# How can I define a maximal amount of ticks in a d3.svg.axis

Tags: d3.js

I have the problem that the labels of my `d3.svg.axis` are sometimes overlapping. Therefor I would like to reduce the maximal amount of ticks and labels to a certain amount.

I can not seem to find a solution in the [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes).

I can not use `axis.tickValues()` because the range is dynamic and can go from several hours to several years.

I have tried using `axis.ticks(9)` but it does not seem to have an effect. You can look at an example on [bl.ocks.org/3181719](http://bl.ocks.org/3181719).

Comment: What happened when you used `ticks()`? Also, have you thought about using `tickValues()`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One of these two should do it for you.  Just specify `axis.ticks(10)` to specify the number of tick marks or `axis.tickValues([1,2,4])` to specify the actual tick marks that should appear.

Since you are using dates, you'll need to do something like this:

```
 .ticks(d3.time.weeks, 2)
```

You can read more about time intervals at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals. You can see an example about how I do this at http://bl.ocks.org/1962173 to update the ticks based on the length of time being shown.

```
if ((maxExtent - minExtent) > 1468800000) {
    x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
    x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b - Week %W'))        
}
else if ((maxExtent - minExtent) > 172800000) {
    x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
    x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b - Week %W'))
}
else {
    x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.hours, 4).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
    x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %e'))
}
```

Comment: I tried using `axis.ticks()` but is does not seem to work. I updated the question with an example. I can not use `axis.tickValues()` because the range is dynamic and can go from several hours to severa years.

Comment: .ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1) save my life. Perfect to switch from fixed ticks value to Week view. Thanks !!

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot. Have been stuck with this issue for sometime now.

Comment: How would you use this with Linear axis/scale?