# How to decrease domain of dates on x axis in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having set of dates on my x-axis and those dates keep on increasing daily so my x axis is getting populated day by day. So I want to show only few dates on my axis. Currently I am using ordinal scale

```
 var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
```

And its domain defined here:

```
xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
                return d.date;
            }).sort(function(a, b) {
                return a - b;
            }));
```

Please suggest how can I show only few dates on my x axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define a maximal amount of ticks in a d3.svg.axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654836/how-can-i-define-a-maximal-amount-of-ticks-in-a-d3-svg-axis)

Comment: @Gilsha he is asking something else...