# Can I define a max number of ticks in a d3.js axis?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, axis-labels

I have a dc.js seriesChart using `d3.scaleTime()` on the X axis. The data changes dynamically, ranging from a single week to a few years, so I don't define a domain or a range for the scaleTime. Instead I'm using dc.js [`elasticX(true)`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX__anchor), which I guess calculates them as needed. I'm also using a [fake group to remove the empty bins](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-elasticx-respond-when-groups-become-empty), in order for the X axis to refresh automatically as the user changes the data filters.

Everything works as expected, but if I filter only one week, I get more ticks than I'd like. Notice that I have only one data point, but up to 4 ticks, for each day:

[image: Too many ticks]

I can use [`axis.ticks`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) to generate only one tick per day:

```js
chart.xAxis()
     .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d'))
     .ticks(d3.timeDay);
```

But then it creates *one tick per day*. If I select a whole year, that's 365 of them overlapping.

I can't use `.ticks(n)` to always generate `n` ticks, because that would bring back the problem I had in the first place: duplicate ticks when the number I set is greater than the number of selected days. And I can't use `.tickValues([ ])` either, because the values are dynamic.

**Is there any way to tell d3 to generate ticks for a given interval, but limited to a max number of ticks?** So in my case, it would actually be "daily if it fits, or every *whatever* days otherwise".

The closest thing I've found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661725/112934), where they change the interval dynamically depending on the range. However, since I'm letting dc.js and Crossfilter deal with the data and filtering, it wouldn't be easy to calculate that. I guess I would have to [attach a renderlet event](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor) to the chart, and use [`xAxisMin()` and `xAxisMax()`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#xAxisMax__anchor)? I think it could work, but it wouldn't look too good. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a first "working" solution... and it's uglier than I tought it would be:

```js
const chart = dc.seriesChart('#myChart')
    // ...
    .x(d3.scaleTime())
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .on('renderlet', updateTicks);
    .xAxis()
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d'))
        .ticks(10); // We set 10 ticks by default
chart.render();

// Needed to prevent infinite loops...
let redrawing = false;

function updateTicks(chart) {
    if (redrawing) {
        redrawing = false;
    } else {
        const days = (chart.xAxisMax() - chart.xAxisMin()) / 86400000;
        if (days < 10) {
            chart.xAxis().ticks(d3.timeDay);
        } else {
            chart.xAxis().ticks(10);
        }
        redrawing = true;
        chart.redraw();
    }
}
```

`xAxisMin()` and `xAxisMax()` values aren't calculated until the chart has already been rendered or redrawn, so I have to use the `renderlet` event instead of `preRedraw`. And since the chart is already drawn, any change I make to the axis won't be effective until the next redraw... so I have to force it myself (and prevent an infinite loop, because my redraw will trigger a new renderlet event).

It's not only ugly code, the axis transition is actually visible on the chart. I could avoid it by using the `pretransition` event instead, as pointed out by Gordon. Or by calculating the min and max values on the `preRender`/`preRedraw` event, directly from the Crossfilter group, but it's starting to feel like a huge overkill.

---

Here is a working-but-still-ugly solution, calculating the min and max myself:

```js
const chart = dc.seriesChart('#myChart')
    // ...
    .x(d3.scaleTime())
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .on('preRender', updateTicks),
    .on('preRedraw', updateTicks);
    .xAxis().tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d'));
chart.render();

function updateTicks(chart) {
    const range = chart.group().all().reduce((accum, d) => minMax(d.key.date, accum), {});
    const days = 1 + ((new Date(range.max) - new Date(range.min)) / 86400000);
    if (days <= 7) {
        chart.xAxis().ticks(d3.timeDay);
    } else if (days <= 30) {
        chart.xAxis().ticks(d3.timeMonday);
    } else {
        chart.xAxis().ticks(d3.timeMonth);
    }
}

function minMax(val, obj) {
    if ((obj.min === undefined) || (val < obj.min)) {
        obj.min = val;
    }
    if ((obj.max === undefined) || (val > obj.max)) {
        obj.max = val;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Not ugly code per se, it's just annoying - traversing the whole data array each time I redraw the chart, only to find the min and max values, which will be calculated again by dc/crossfilter/d3 anyway.

Comment: Can you use `pretransition` instead of `renderlet`? That should be after it's drawn but without waiting for transitions to complete. I really hate the extra redraw, too... `preRedraw` would solve all these problems, maybe you could try it with `chart.x().domain()[0]`, `chart.x().domain()[1]` instead of `xAxisMin`, `xAxisMax` (which I'm surprised don't work since redraw is after render). Guess I'd need a running example to help further...

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. `pretransition` could solve the visible redraw, but it would still be there in the code, haunting me... :). I have it working with `preRedraw` _and_ `preRender`, looking for the min and max myself (`chart.group().all().reduce( ... )`), which I hate too. I'll try with `.x().domain()` instead, or try to include a MCVE fiddle if it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope. On the "pre" events, `x().domain()` still has the current value, not the one which will be used for the redraw. Just the same as `xAxisMin()`. So it's either `pretransition` and force another redraw, or get the min and max myself, I guess.

Comment: I don't know what would make the data stale like that. I guess you are replacing the group? `xAxisMin` should reflect the current group data as soon as the group is replaced. I bet it is something to do with the series chart. I'll try to repro tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was the expected behavior: you ask for the min-max before redrawing, then you get the "old" values. I'll update the question with a jsFiddle as soon as I can

Comment: Okay, I added a series progression example and was able to repro this issue. The problem is that the series chart creates a static, nested copy of the data when it redraws, and passes that down to the child charts. And the composite chart `xAxisMin` delegates to the children, so you see stale data. I think your new solution is about as good as it gets given the current architecture. :-/ It's not something you'd have to do with any other chart.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon. I was still working on the jsFiddle (it's a lot of code to clean and simplify). Just curious, would it be the same with a compositeChart instead of seriesChart?

Comment: No, it's a peculiarity of the series chart because it splits the data using `d3.nest` and [creates fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/84426c3934b2329041a65e9a482df53a561ac838/src/series-chart.js#L61) for each of the child charts from the split data. During redraw. Highly unusual! It makes me think that the series function would be better as a data preprocessor than a "chart".